# How to include variables and functions common to a number of CasperJS scripts?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, require

Let's say I need CasperJS to report progress steps to a localhost server. I couldn't user `casper.open` to send a POST request because it'd "switch" pages so to speak and would be unable to continue other steps properly.

I sidestepped this issue by evaluating an `XMLHttpRequest()` inside the browser to ping to localhost. Not ideal but it works.

As the number of the scripts grow, I'd rather move this common functionality into a module, which is to say, I want to move a number of functions into a separate module.

It's my understanding CasperJS doesn't work like node.js does so `require()` rules are different. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CasperJS is based on PhantomJS you can use its [module system](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.7.html), which is *"modelled after [CommonJS Modules 1.1](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1)"*

1. You can `require` the module file by its path, full or relative.

   ```
   var tools = require("./tools.js");
   var tools = require("./lib/utils/tools.js");
   var tools = require("/home/scraping/project/lib/utils/tools.js");
   ```
2. Or you can follow node.js convention and create a subfolder `node_modules/module_name` in your project's folder, and place module's code into `index.js` file. It would then reside in this path:

   ```
   ./node_modules/tools/index.js
   ```

After that require it in CasperJS script:

`var tools = require("tools")`;

Module would export its functions in this way:

```
function test(){
    console.log("This is test");
}

module.exports = {
    test: test
};
```